# signal in baseband

Tags: digital-communications

I have a signal $s(t)$ which is defined as $s(t)=f(t)+g(t)$ in the time domain.  In the frequency domain, the signal $f$ is a baseband signal whereas the signal $g$ is a signal that occupies the right side of the bandwidth of signal $f$.

Thus is my questions:
1)Can we say that $g$ is baseband when it is not centered at $0$ in the spectral domain? Similarly for the signal $s$.

2. Taking into account the first question, is it correct to sum these $2$ signals even if in the frequency domain $g$ is not centered at $0$?

Comment: Do you know about complex-valued signals versus real signals?  And, since $f$ is often used to denote _frequency_, do you _have_ to call signals $f(t)$ and $g(t)$? Or would you consider _editing_ your question to change $f$ and $g$ to, say, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$?

Comment: Your second question makes no sense. You can add these signals. Who or what would stop you?